# Facebook SDK share on iOS not working

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-share, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am working on sharing a content on Facebook for an iOS app using Swift.

I have written a singleton class called FBManager and a function as below.

```
func shareContent(content:String, contentURL:String?, contentTitle:String? , fromController controller:UIViewController {
        let shareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
        let shareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()

        shareLinkContent.contentDescription = content

        if let url = contentURL
        {
            shareLinkContent.contentURL = NSURL(string: url)
        }

        if let title = contentTitle
        {
            shareLinkContent.contentTitle = title
        }

        shareDialog.delegate = self
        shareDialog.fromViewController = controller
        shareDialog.shareContent = shareLinkContent
        shareDialog.show()
  }
```

But this does not even show a share dialog both on iOS 8 and iOS 9. 
Instead the following delegate method gets called

```
func sharer(sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
}
```

with the error - "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.share error 2.)"

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook SDK's error codes are somewhat ambiguous because they cover rather large domains of errors. The code you provided does not really show the content of the variables and so I cannot pinpoint the problem. However, `com.facebook.sdk.share error 2` is an *Invalid Argument* error, which usually arises from an invalid format of one or more members of `FBSDKShareLinkContent`.

Generally, you can use the `FBSDKErrorCode` enum to switch over the `(error as NSError).code` and find which domain it belongs to. (In this case, it'll point to Invalid Argument)

You can also `print(error)` directly in the `didFailWithError` delegate method, which will output a very descriptive log of the error and what caused it specifically.

Check your `contentURL`, make sure it starts with `http://` or `https://` or any other valid protocol. Same for the `imageURL` if you're using or planning to use one. This most likely caused your error!

[The SDK's error codes reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors) may be helpful too.